# configatron shorthand for namespaces

Tags: ruby, configuration, configatron

Is there a way to avoid typing the namespace each time when using the configatron gem?
Say, you have

```
  configatron.email.pop.address = 1
  configatron.email.pop.port = 2
```

Can I configure port and address by somehow typing `configatron.email.pop` only once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy thing you can do is this.

```
configatron.email.pop.tap do|pop|
  pop.address = 'localhost'
  pop.port = 22
end
```

Or even this.

```
pop = configatron.email.pop
pop.address = 'localhost'
pop.port = 22
```

You could try adding singleton methods to the configatron object too.

```
class << configatron
  def pop; email.pop; end
end

configatron.pop.address = 'localhost'
configatron.pop.port = 22
```

Or even this.

```
class << configatron
  def pop_address; email.pop.address; end
  def pop_address=(addr); email.pop.address = addr; end
end

configatron.pop_address = 'address'
```

But this may end up breaking things (I'm assuming configatron works on method_missing).  And it doesn't save much typing, but it can let you make some handy shortcuts to things hidden several namespaces deep.

Maybe you should just stick it out with the verbosity here though.

Comment: Are you using the `tap` method?